# Dual boot Windows and Ubuntu where Ubuntu does not have internet connection

Tags: dual-boot

I am installing ubuntu as dual boot on my windows pc. While installing it usually has internet to download updates. This is not the case with my ubuntu, it has no internet connection during installation and afterwards there is still no internet connection.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean it does not have internet connection. Have you not provided it or the internet is connected and not detected. If the second case then which kind of connected are you using a LAN or a Wireless connection

Comment: the network icon is not available, i am using wireless but its not available

Comment: Then this seems like a driver issue to me, can you tell us which System you are using, and paste results for `lspci` in your question

Comment: i tried to install it on a VM with virtual box, then i have internet. but I prefer to install it dual boot

Comment: usually when i install ubuntu, it gives an option to enter the wireless password then it connects to internet before starting install. while installing it then downloads updates. the prompt for the wifi does not appear and the download updates button while installing is disabled, but ticked.

Comment: As I said, this seems to be a driver issue. Can you please open up terminal and run `lspci` and paste the results here

Comment: how can i run terminal if ubuntu is not yet installed? so its on the installer that i need it to connect to the wifi

Comment: run the terminal in the live ubuntu which you are using to install the OS. The installation disc of ubuntu should give you the capability of running Live OS without installation

Comment: not sure how to add pics on here, its a lot to type....

Comment: upload it to something like imgur or something and paste the link here

Comment: here is a link to the file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4vbbkjk4elazk5/DSC_0066.JPG?dl=0

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have internet connection while installing ubuntu, but strictly speaking it is optional. You can install ubuntu without connecting to internet.
After that, if you want to install some additional softwares, then package manager (apt-get) is highly recommended, which needs active internet connection.

Comment: i want to install with internet, not without, without is a pain

Comment: ok ok. I had little bit confusion.